# async/await method crash web services response in Android but same code work successfully in Window Phone and iOS apps in xamarin Native Application

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, xamarin, xamarin.android

**async/await method crash web services response in Android but same code work successfully in Window Phone and iOS apps in xamarin Native Application.**

**Xamarin Native Application (PCL)**

I have created a Native application using portable Class library.

I request to REST API that gives the following response.

```
{
code: 200,
status: "ok",
message: "hello"
}
```

my Portable class library code in xamarin.forms is

**test.xaml.cs**

```
public class jsonResponseClass
{
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }
}
public partial class test : ContentPage
{
        public async void getDatas()
        {
            var cl = new HttpClient();
            var result = await cl.GetStringAsync("http://192.168.1.125/apps/jara/web/api/user/test");
            jsonResponseClass des = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonResponseClass>(result);
            lbl1.Text = des.code + " " + des.status + " " + des.message;
        }
        public test()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            getDatas();
        }
}
```

**Main file in Portable class library (PCL)**

**App.cs**

```
namespace NativeAppsWithWCF
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            MainPage = new test();
        }
        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
}
```

my Visual studio solution explorer

[image]

Using this above code I can successfully show output in iOS and Window Phone Apps.

But when I Run Android apps then crash the apps and not show output.

When I debug Android program then cursor remove after this line.

```
var result = await
cl.GetStringAsync("http://192.168.1.125/apps/jara/web/api/user/test");
```

After this line stop the execution of program.

**Which means it won't wait for the method to finish executing**

See the screen after got error..

[image]

How to prevent this error?

Comment: Can you post the contents of the exception?

Comment: You should avoid `async void` methods.

Comment: if it's unhandled, then something threw an exception, and you have nothing that catches. why not `try { your stuff } catch ...` and SEE what the exception is?

Comment: Already i have tried to using try....catch.... debug cursor are successfully execute try block code... but after below line code execution end... var result = await cl.GetStringAsync("192.168.1.125/apps/jara/web/api/user/test");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have solved the problem after lots of R&D.

Problem in Network Connectivity.

I have solve this issue after setting of Network Connectivity in Android Emulator.

**Follow Below step..**

Open **VS Android Emulator >> Go to Setting  >> Turn ON WIFI >>**

There are **"Wired eth1"**  Network available.

**Long Press on "Wired eth1" Network**

Then **Click on  >> Modify Network >> Change "IP Setting" as "Static" >>**

**Change IP address of your Network.**

After this setting I have **Solved** my Issue and Get a Response from **REST API**.

Thank you.